# Segregating the read-only and read-write in Spring/J2EE Apps

Tags: mysql, jpa, design-patterns, architecture, spring-data

We using Spring, Spring-Data and JPA in our project.

For production servers, we would like to setup database cluster such that all read queries are directed to one server and all write queries are directed to another server.

This obviously will require some changes in the way the DAOs are built.

Does anyone know how to achieve this if one has, so far, been following cook-book style DAO creations using Spring-Data/JPA where a DAO implementation is responsible for both reads and writes?  What kind of changes in architecture will be needed to segregate the two types of calls?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.6

Comment: In that case, would [ReplicationDriver](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html) work for you?  I have tried it before and it works well.  The `ReplicationDriver` class is just like the regular MySQL `Driver` class, just that it allows you to pass more than one server host in the JDBC URL.  If you annotate read-only methods in your code with `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`, the `ReplicationDriver` will always treat the first host in the JDBC URL as the write-to host and the others as read-only.

Comment: Thanks.  That looks promising.  We have a multi-master setup, do we need to move to master-slave kind of setup for it to work

Comment: No, not required.  For example, I once built a sample app with a single MySQL master and each app server ran a slave copy.  All of these were in the same rack so replication did not fail too often.  Then, we used the JDBC URL `jdbc:mysql:replication://master.example.com,local.example.com`, where `master.example.com` resolved to the master and `local.example.com` to the local server.  So, although there were many slaves, each app server would only be aware of one (itself) due to the way the JDBC URL was crafted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When using MySQL, it is common for Java developers to use [Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) as the JDBC driver.  Developers typically use the Connector/J `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class, with a URL such as `jdbc:mysql://host[:port]/database` to connect to MySQL databases.

Connector/J offers another driver called [`ReplicationDriver`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html) that allows an application to load-balance between multiple MySQL hosts.  When using `ReplicationDriver`, the JDBC URL changes to `jdbc:mysql:replication://master-host[:master-port][,slave-1-host[:slave-1-port]][,slave-2-host[:slave-2-port]]/database`.  This allows the application to connect to one of multiple servers depending on which one is available at any given point in time.

When using the `ReplicationDriver`, if a JDBC connection is set to `read-only`, the driver treats the first host declared in the URL as a `read-write` host and all others as `read-only` hosts.  Developers can take advantage of this in a Spring application by structuring their code as follows:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {
   public SomeDataType readSomething(...) { ... }

   @Transactional(readOnly = false)
   public void writeSomething(...) { ... }
}
```

With code like this, whenever the method `readSomething` is called, the Spring transaction management code will obtain a JDBC `Connection` and call `setReadOnly(true)` on it because the service methods are annotated with `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` by default.  This will make all database queries from the `readSomething` method to go to one of the non-master MySQL hosts, load-balanced in a round-robin fashion.  Similarly, whenever `writeSomething` is called, Spring will call `setReadOnly(false)` on the underlying JDBC `Connection`, forcing the database queries to go to the master server.

This strategy allows the application to direct all read-only traffic to one set of MySQL servers and all read-write traffic to a different server, without changing the application's logical architecture or the developers having to worry about different database hosts and roles.

Comment: I know this is an older post, but I'm using Spring (4.2.x) with hibernate (5.1.x) with the mysql replication driver but all queries still seem to go to the master even with @Transactional(readOnly = true).  It seems that the underlying connection isn't being set to readOnly, has anyone else come across/solved this?

Comment: I ended up refactoring my code which was just the hibernate specific API (ie:SessionFactory) to standard JPA (ie:  EntityManager) and that resolved my issues.

Answer (score 3):

Well, what your are talking about is actually called CQRS (http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html).
I would suggest reading some of the concept guidelines before making attempts of implementing it.

As for your question, for short first victory, I would suggest by starting dividing the DAL's services into Finder classes and Repository classes which will be used by a higher, business oriented services.

Finders will suit a read-only access, exposing only getBy...() methods and lookups that return custom result objects, such as reports, and their underlying implementation is tailored to work against the read-only database.

Repositories on the other hand, will suit a write-only / getById() methods and their underlying implementation is tailored to work against the write-only database.

The only thing left is the synchronisation between those databases.
This can be achieved quite simply by technical solutions such as: database replication, postponed updates to the read-only database after changes were made to the write-only database (eventual consistency).