# How to configure Spring data JPA to work with replicated Postgresql?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Consider I have a cluster of postgresql nodes with one master and others as replicas. All writes should go to master, all reads should go to replicas. The question is - how to properly configure Spring Data JPA to work with such setup, so that all saves go to master and all selects go to replicas automatically?

Comment: Connections to the database are made through a JDBC driver. The official Postgres JDBC driver does not support the scenario you are looking for. The supported options are explained in [the Postgres documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html). At the bottom of the page there seems to be a recommendation to use two different data sources, one for read-only operations and another for write operations. You could write your own `DataSource` class that delegates to one of two underlying data sources based on operation type.

Comment: Thx @manish, it's a pity to hear this, because read replica is quite a popular solution to scale reads and Spring Data JPA is a popular solution to access the database, so if additional programming is needed to accompany the official driver, it's not that good for me. Maybe you can advice some other DB which does have such feature out of the box for Java?

Comment: MySQL has a `ReplicationDriver`. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938574/segregating-the-read-only-and-read-write-in-spring-j2ee-apps) for details.

Comment: Thx! MySQL still does have some troubles https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAiVsbXVP6k , but the built in replication feature in driver could be promising enough to use it