# Spring Data JPA Multiple Data Sources

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have been following this link trying to configure two or more data sources.

https://www.ccampo.me/java/spring/2016/02/13/multi-datasource-spring-boot.html

It explains how to define two data sources, But did not explains how to actually use them while querying.

I have created configuration class & added prop in application.prop file. But how to define them in repo function/service function?

**Controller**

```
public class EmpController {
  @RequestMapping("/abcd")
  public List<Employee> findAll() { return empService.findAll(); }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class EmpService {
    @Autowired
    private EmpRepository empRepo;

    public List<Employee> findAll() { return empRepo.findAll(); }
}
```

**Repo**

```
public interface EmpRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {}
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {
  @Bean
  @Primary
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.primary")
  public DataSource numberMasterDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.secondary")
  public DataSource provisioningDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
# Primary DataSource configuration
datasource.primary.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/jpa
datasource.primary.username=root
datasource.primary.password=root
# Any of the other Spring supported properties below...

# Secondary DataSource configuration
datasource.secondary.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/jpa2
datasource.secondary.username=root
datasource.secondary.password=root
```

Also I donot want to have separate repositories for different datasources as
I have different DBs for Read & Write. So all my insert queries will be on one server & read queries on other server. If I create different repo/service for read & write, too much redundant code will be there

Comment: Show your query code?

Comment: Edited the question for code

Comment: @AnkitBansal, are the databases identical, and always will be identical (for example, one being the read replica of the other)? If not, the different database structures automatically imply that they do not store the same (exact) data. Hence, both will require different entities and therefore separate repositories.

Comment: Yes databases are similar(replica) and hence store same data, So logically I can use same entities & repo.

Comment: @AnkitBansal, your original post had the `mysql` tag on it but doesn't any more. Is that deliberate? Would a MySQL-specific solution work?

Comment: I need JPA hibernate specific solution. Also I would be using jooQ also, so need solution for that also. but thats the problem for some other time. One problem at a time

Comment: This cannot be solved with JPA. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938574/segregating-the-read-only-and-read-write-in-spring-j2ee-apps) for a MySQL-specific solution where you can keep a single set of entities and repositories.

Comment: Isnt there is any annotation based solution? what about @DataSourceDefinition

Comment: It there any other working Spring data JPA Hibernate Solution with diff repo & service apart from the answer below which is not using embedded database like h2 and using mysql databae.

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at detailed [example](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases) . You will have configure two different datasources, separate repositories and models using packages and configure datasource for specific packages.

Comment: I have to work with same repo i.e. cannot create diff repo for diff DB.

Comment: So you want all employees from two different datasources with one query?

Comment: I have diff databases for Read & write. So while insert I will be using different DB & for read queries, I will be using 2nd database, Since there are too many modules. I donot want to create separate repo / service for read & write. too much redundant code.

Comment: @AnkitBansal, can you add these details to the question itself? This is a very important piece of information and readers may not read it since right now it is inside a comment to an answer.